# docker-compose down default_network error

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose with some php, mysql and so on starting. After a few days, I cannot bring them down as everything stopps instead of mysql. It always gives me the following error:

```
ERROR: network docker_default has active endpoints
```

this is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  php:
    build: php-docker/.
    container_name: php
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - /var/www/:/var/www/
    links:
      - mysql:mysql
    restart: always

  nginx:
    build: nginx-docker/.
    container_name: nginx
    links:
      - php
      - mysql:mysql
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql:3306
    ports:
      - "80:80"

    volumes:
      - /var/log/nginx:/var/log/nginx
      - /var/www/:/var/www/
      - /var/logs/nginx:/var/logs/nginx
      - /var/config/nginx/certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - /var/config/nginx/sites-enabled:/etc/nginx/sites-available
    restart: always

  mysql:
    build: mysql-docker/.
    container_name: mysql
    volumes:
      - /var/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pw
      MYSQL_USER: florian
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pw
      MYSQL_DATABASE: database
    restart: always


  phpmyadmin:
    build: phpmyadmin/.
    links:
     - mysql:db
    ports:
     - 1234:80
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    environment:
     PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
     PMA_USERNAME: florian
     PMA_PASSWORD: pw
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pw
    restart: always
```

`docker network inspect docker_default` gives me:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "docker_default",
        "Id": "1ed93da1a82efdab065e3a833067615e2d8b76336968a2591584af5874f07622",
        "Created": "2017-03-08T07:21:34.969179141Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Containers": {
            "85985605f1c0c20e5ee9fedc95800327f782beafc0049f51e645146d2e954b7d": {
                "Name": "mysql",
                "EndpointID": "84fb19cd428f8b0ba764b396362727d9809cd1cfea536e648bfc4752c5cb6b27",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

### UPDATE

Seems that `docker rm mysql -f` stopped the mysql container, but the network is running.

Removed the network with `docker network disconnect -f docker_default mysql` But I'm pretty interested in how I got into this situation. any ideas?

Comment: What's still running on the network? `docker network inspect docker_default` should list the containers. Is mysql really left justified in your yml and not spaced in?

Comment: Also see if you currently have containers running: `docker container ls -a`

Comment: @BMitch I updated the question and no mysql is not left justified, was my fault in the question.

Comment: @nateleavitt mysql is running

Comment: Any reason you can see that mysql is refusing to stop? Can you stop it manually, any logs available? Please include output from the command line when you attempt to stop it.

Comment: @BMitch I got it down and updated the question... any ideas why it got into that situation?

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here to tell you why mysql didn't stop, particularly since it stopped for you when you ran the `docker rm`.

Comment: Always good to try restarting Docker.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

I resolved a similar problem when I added this after rename services in by docker-compose.yml file before stop container

```
docker-compose down --remove-orphans
```

Answer (score 90):

I'm guessing you edited the docker-compose file while you were currently running...?

Sometimes if you edit the docker-compose file before doing a `docker-compose down` it will then have a mismatch in what docker-compose will attempt to stop. First run `docker rm 8598560` to stop the currently running container.  From there, make sure you do a `docker-compose down` before editing the file. Once you stop the container, `docker-compose up` should work.

Comment: no I didn't edit the compose file while running. I did really nothing. thought my webserver was up and running. but sometimes I had issues connecting to the wordpress. because of database issues. then I tried to get it down and my question started...

Comment: Okay.. does it seem to be operating normally now?

Comment: It may be a sleep issue. Sometimes things can get out of sync when mac sleeps. There is currently a time issue with macs right now, but I'm not even sure you're running a mac. I usually do a `docker-compose down` at the end of my day.

Comment: This command didn't work in my case, but `docker-compose stop container_id` helped

Comment: @Florian maybe you changed the path to the docker-compose.yml file between running the up and down? That was the case in my case.

Comment: Removing container didn't work for me (it was already deleted). For me, it fixed after a reboot.

Comment: In my case, docker inspect network didn't show any active Containers for this network. Restarting docker and running a `docker system prune --all` removed the network and things worked again.

Comment: In my case I ha just forgotten to specify the same project name (-p) I had used for the docker-compose up.

Answer (score 63):

You need to disconnect stale endpoint(s) from the network. First, get the endpoint names with

```
docker network inspect <network>
```

You can find your endpoints in the output JSON: `Containers -> Name`. Now, simply force disconnect them with:

```
docker network disconnect -f <network> <endpoint>
```

Comment: In our case there are not any endpoint in inspect.

Comment: I had the same issue, no endpoints. docker system prune - helped

Comment: For some reason, I had a lot of networks and had to remove them one by one, it works, though.

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately none of above worked for me. Restarting the docker service solved the problem.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me. `systemctl restart docker`

Comment: Being on a mac makes this, at least for me, a little bit difficult.
Restarting my docker desktop is pretty much the same as command,  and  that worked well enough.

Comment: In case someone needs to do this on a mac on cli: `killall Docker && open /Applications/Docker.app`

Answer (score 7):

I happened to run into this error message because I had two networks with the same name (copy/paste mistake).

What I did to fix it:

- `docker-compose down` - ignore errors
- `docker network list` - note if any container is using it and stop if if necessary
- `docker network prune` to remove all dangling networks, although you may want to just `docker network rm <network name>`
- rename the second network to a unique name
- `docker-compose up`

Comment: `docker-compose up --remove-orphans` to remove leftover containers

Comment: This did it for me! Specifically `docker network prune`!

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, I ran into this same issue and `docker compose down --remove-orphans` resolved the issue for me. I was curious what happened in the first place and for me it came down to having multiple docker compose YAML files in the directory where I was running the command.

When I explicitly specify the compose file I built the service from, it works fine.

eg.

You're in a directory that has two docker compose files, `docker-compose-1.yml` and `docker-compose-2.yml` and you build your service using the first file.

`docker compose -f docker-compose-1.yml up --build -d`

If you run `docker compose down` it will raise the error. As soon as you specify the file name, it shuts down the container as expected.

`docker compose -f docker-compose-1.yml down`

Answer (score 2):

I tested all the solutions contained in this post and nothing worked.
After much research, I identified that what causes this is possibly a package conflict.

I'm using Ubuntu 22 LTS, I installed docker with SNAP and apparently this may have damaged the installation.

What worked for me was:

1 -> sudo aa-remove-unknown
2 -> docker-compose down

This will remove unnecessary references and return Docker to its correct functioning.

Answer (score 0):

service docker restart

then remove the network normally

docker network rm [network name]

Answer (score 0):

**This issue happens rarely while running exceptional dozens of services** ( in parallel ) on the same instance, but unfortunately docker-compose could not establish deployment / recreation operation of these containers as a result of an "`active network interface"` that is bind and stuck.

I also enabled running flags such as:

- `force-recreate` ( Recreate containers even if their configuration and image haven’t changed )
  or
- `remove-orphans` flags(Remove containers for services not defined in
  the Compose file.)

but it did not help.

**Eventually I came into conclusion that restarting docker
engine is the last resort** - docker closes any network connections that are associated with the docker daemon ( connection between containers and between the api )-  this action
solved this problem  ( `sudo service docker restart` )